# Three Queries Faster than One -- What's Wrong with my Joins?

Tags: mysql, join

I've got a JPA ManyToMany relationship set up, which gives me three important tables: my Ticket table, my Join table, and my Inventory table. They're InnoDB tables on MySQL 5.1. The relevant bits are:

```
Ticket:
+--------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID     | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Status | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

JoinTable:
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| InventoryID | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | Foreign Key - Inventory
| TicketID    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | Foreign Key - Ticket
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+

Inventory:
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| TStampString | varchar(32)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

TStampStrings are of the form "yyyy.mm.dd HH:MM:SS Z" (for example, '2010.03.19 22:27:57 GMT'). Right now all of the Tickets created directly correspond to some specific hour TStampString, so that `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Ticket;` is the same as `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(SUBSTRING(TStampString, 1, 13))) FROM Inventory;`

What I'd like to do is regroup certain Tickets based on the minute granularity of a TStampString: (SUBSTRING(TStampString, 1, 16)). So I'm profiling and testing the SELECT of an INSERT INTO ... SELECT statement:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SUBSTRING(i.TStampString, 1, 16) FROM Ticket t JOIN JoinTable j
ON t.ID = j.TicketID JOIN Inventory i ON j.InventoryID = i.ID WHERE t.Status
= 'Regroup' GROUP BY SUBSTRING(i.TStampString, 1, 16);

+--+------+---+--------+-------------+-----+-----+----------+-------+-----------+
|id| type |tbl| type   | psbl_keys   | key | len | ref      | rows  | Extra     |
+--+------+---+--------+-------------+-----+-----+----------+-------+-----------+
|1 | SMPL | t | ALL    | PRI         | NULL| NULL| NULL     | 35569 | where     |
|  |      |   |        |             |     |     |          |       | +temporary|
|  |      |   |        |             |     |     |          |       | +filesort |
|1 | SMPL | j | ref    | PRI,FK1,FK2 | FK2 | 4   | t.ID     |   378 | index     |
|1 | SMPL | i | eq_ref | PRI         | PRI | 4   | j.Invent |     1 |           |
|  |      |   |        |             |     |     |    oryID |       |           |
+--+------+---+--------+-------------+-----+-----+----------+-------+-----------+
```

What this implies to me is that for each row in Ticket, MySQL first does the joins then later decides that the row is invalid due to the WHERE clause. Certainly the runtime is abominable (I gave up after 30 minutes). Note that it goes no faster with t.Status = 'Regroup' moved to the first JOIN clause and no WHERE clause.

But what's interesting is that if I run this query manually in three steps, doing what I thought the optimizer would do, each step returns almost immediately:

```
--Step 1: Select relevant Tickets (results dumped to file)
SELECT ID FROM Ticket WHERE Status = 'Regroup';

--Step 2: Get relevant Inventory entries
SELECT InventoryID FROM JoinTable WHERE TicketID IN (step 1s file);

--Step 3: Select what I wanted all along
SELECT SUBSTRING(TStampString, 1, 16) FROM Inventory WHERE ID IN (step 2s file)
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(TStampString, 1, 16);
```

On my particular tables, the first query gives 154 results, the second creates 206,598 lines, and the third query returns 9198 rows. All of them combined take ~2 minutes to run, with the last query having the only significant runtime.

Dumping the intermediate results to a file is cumbersome, and more importantly I'd like to know how to write my original query such that it runs reasonably. So how do I structure this three-table-join such that it runs as fast as I know is possible?

**UPDATE**: I've added a prefix index on Status(16), which changes my EXPLAIN profile rows to 153, 378, and 1 respectively (since the first row has a key to use). The JOIN version of my query now takes ~6 minutes, which is tolerable but still considerably slower than the manual version. I'd still like to know why the join is performing sorely suboptimally, but it may be that one can't create independent subqueries in buggy MySQL 5.1. If enough time passes I'll accept Add Index as the solution to my problem, although it's not exactly the answer to my question.

In the end I did end up manually recreating every step of the join on disk. Tens of thousands of files each with a thousand queries was still significantly faster than anything I could get my version of MySQL to do. But since that process would be horribly specific and unhelpful for the layman, I'm accepting ypercube's answer of Add (Partial) Indexes.

Comment: Does the `Status` column really have to be `longtext` and not some shorter type, like `VARCHAR(255)`?

Comment: I had just noticed that when posting this question; I thought I'd told JPA that I wanted a VARCHAR(16), but I guess it didn't take the hint. Don't want to change schemas this late into production, though.

Comment: Are the tables InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: how about selecting distinct() and dropping the group by?

Comment: @MarkusMikkolainen - This is just an exemplary query. I'll be doing a few more things with the same form, one of which will involve selecting a more distinct column not mentioned here for brevity reasons. I apologize if that makes my contrived example a bit misleading. @ ypercube - Updated the original post to say InnoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do to speed up the query:

- Add an index on `Status`. Even if you don't change the type to `VARCHAR`, you can still add a partial index:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE Ticket
    ADD INDEX status_idx
      Status(16) ;
  ```
- I assume that the Primary key of the Join table is `(InventoryID, TicketID)`. You can add another index on `(TicketID, InventoryID)` as well. This may not benefit this particular query but it will be helpful in other queries you'll have.

The answer on why this happens is that the optimizer does not always choose the best plan. You can try this variation of your query and see how the `EXPLAIN` plan differs and if there is any efficiency gain:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(i.TStampString, 1, 16) 
FROM 
    ( SELECT (DISTINCT) j.InventoryID 
      FROM Ticket t 
        JOIN JoinTable j
          ON t.ID = j.TicketID 
      WHERE t.Status = 'Regroup' 
    ) AS tmp
  JOIN Inventory i 
    ON tmp.InventoryID = i.ID
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(i.TStampString, 1, 16) ;
```

Comment: Certainly this would make this specific query go faster, but my greater concern is why naively executing the queries sequentially performs significantly better than what should be the cleaner form. I'd like to believe there's some way to structure the query against the existing tables such that it performs like my manual imitations.

Comment: The EXPLAIN on your suggestion is interesting in that it references tmp (206598 rows; select_type PRIMARY -- that's good), then i (1 row; PRIMARY), then t (35569 rows; DERIVED), then j (378 rows; DERIVED). That by itself is no good, but it's curious that the optimizer knows exactly how many rows should be involved in the first step. If that's the case, why does it need to reference t again? Perhaps we can get where we want to be if we can get MySQL to forget about t outside of the temporary table. (Clocking out for the day, by the way. Thanks for the ongoing effort. Will be back in the AMs.)

Answer (score -1):

try giving the first substring-clause an alias and using it in the group-by.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(i.TStampString, 1, 16) as blaa FROM Ticket t JOIN JoinTable j
ON t.ID = j.TicketID JOIN Inventory i ON j.InventoryID = i.ID WHERE t.Status
= 'Regroup' GROUP BY blaa;
```

also avoid the join altogether since you dont need it..

```
SELECT distinct(SUBSTRING(i.TStampString, 1,16)) from inventory i where i.ID in 
 ( select id from JoinTable j where j.TicketID in 
    (select id from Ticket t where t.Status = 'Regroup'));
```

would that work?

btw. you do have an index on the Status field ?

Comment: I do not have an index on the Status field; this is the only query that filters on it, and this query didn't show up until late in production. Also, I'm given to understand that joins are almost always better than subqueries (in this case dependent subqueries because MySQL 5.1 is buggy). Certainly the EXPLAIN output of your second suggestion does a full scan on i (17145585 rows) crossed with a full scan on j (16576146 rows) followed by a primary key join on t. That suggests significantly worse performance than the original query.

Comment: `col IN (SELECT ... FROM table)` is usually not efficient in MySQL. Nested queries with `IN` doubles the inefficiency.